# What is the proper method of grouping a Collection in Windows Store App (Metro) using LINQ and VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, linq, listview, grouping, collectionviewsource

I'm a fairly novice programmer, and making a Windows Store App. I have an object that contains an `ObservableCollection(Of T)` that I want to group for display in a `ListView`. Using LINQ to return a set of grouped items seems like it would be the best and easiest choice. Every piece of documentation I could find says that Group By returns `IEnumerable(Of IGrouping(Of TKey, TItem))` and you set `CollectionViewSource.IsSourceGrouped` to True, bind to the CVS and it should all work perfectly. Right?

Not so much.

I have a class that contains

```
Public Property Items As ObservableCollection(Of Item)

Public ReadOnly Property GroupedItems As IEnumerable
    Get
        ' Return grouped items
    End Get
End Property
```

And in the XAML for the page, where `GroupedItems` is set as the `Page`'s `DataContext` in code-behind:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Name="GroupedItems" Source="{Binding}" IsSourceGrouped="True" />
</Page.Resources>

<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource GroupedItems}}">
        <ListView.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!-- Template -->
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </ListView.GroupStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <!-- Template -->
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

Now, if I bind the `ListView` to the `ObservableCollection(Of Item)` directly, the `ListView` renders all the items as expected, following the `ItemTemplate`. But when it is bound to the supposedly-grouped `CollectionViewSource`, the `ListView` renders the groups according to the `HeaderTemplate`, but it doesn't render any of the items within the group.

I've inspected the results of the LINQ logic:

```
Dim x = From i As Item In Items
        Group i By Key = i.SubItem Into Group
```

And `x` has a `Key` property and a `Group` property, though it is some kind of IEnumerable(Of anonymous) type rather than an `IEnumerable(Of IGrouping(Of TKey, TItem))`.

So what am I doing wrong here? Is there another caveat to the VB.NET implementation of LINQ that I'm missing? Is there a property I'm forgetting to set? What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, though I don't know that it is the ideal solution. Because the result of the LINQ query places the items in the `Group` property of its anonymous type, `CollectionViewSource` needs to know that. So by adding `ItemsPath="Group"` to the XAML defining the `CollectionViewSource`, it now displays both the group headers and the containing items.